# Trying to get property of non-object when an array used two times in for-each loop Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have passed a data from the controller to the view as you can see:

```
    public function ViewDemmandes(){
  $listdemmande = Demmande::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(5);
  $listvillee=Ville::all();
  $listcategorie=Categorie::all();
  $listepublic=Publiccibles::all();
  $villes = $listvillee;
  $demmande = $listdemmande;
  $categorie = $listcategorie;
  $pulics=$listepublic;
  return view("demmande.demmandes",compact('listepublic','demmande','villes','categorie'));
}
```

I have tried to use `$cateoriein` into two part of my code.

```
           <select   id="selectType" class="form-control">
            @foreach ($categorie as $categorie )
              <option value= {{$categorie->id}} >{{$categorie->nom}</option>
            @endforeach
          </select>
```

and

```
                      <li><i class="material-icons">lightbulb_outline</i> 
                      Type :
                       @foreach($categorie as $type)
                        {{$type->nom}}
                       @endforeach
                     </li>
```

for the first it is working fine but in the second i got this error

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\wamp\www\project\resources\views\demmande\demmandes.blade.php)
```

Which mistake i have done?

Comment: `$type` is not an opject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I think it would be a best practice to keep you code readable at all time. This way other people are able to understand it better.

The problem here has to do with your variable names. You are overwriting values because you are using the same variable name for the array and the value.

Example:

```
$category = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

var_dump($category); // array (3) { [0] => "a", [1] => "b", [2] => "c"}

foreach ($category as $category) { // array and value variable name are the same
    echo $category; // This echos a, b and c
}

var_dump($category); // string (1) "c"
```

As you can see after the `foreach` loop the `$category` variable has the last value of your array.

A simple fix would be renaming one of the variables in the foreach:

```
$categories = ['a', 'b', 'c']; // Different name (plural of category)

var_dump($categories); // array (3) { [0] => "a", [1] => "b", [2] => "c"}

foreach ($categories as $category) { // array and value variable name are different
    echo $category; // This echos a, b and c
}

var_dump($categories); // array (3) { [0] => "a", [1] => "b", [2] => "c"}
```

This time `$categories` still has the same value as before the `foreach` and can be looped again.